# laravel 4 ajax datatype json request send and receive not working

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4

im trying to do a simple ajax request with data type json but laravel keeps failing to get the data passed from the request

```
 $.ajax({                   
                    url:"http://localhost/laravel/public/ajaxHandler/execute",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { what: 'demo' }
              }).done(function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                });
```

My route is as so

```
Route::controller('ajaxHandler', 'ajaxhandlerController');
```

and my controller is as so

```
public function postExecute()
{
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    die;
}
```

But it does not work.

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Failing how exactly? What are you doing besides having all set? Any error messages?

Comment: Can you directly access this route from your browser's address bar using `http://localhost/laravel/public/ajaxHandler/execute` ?

Comment: no im not able to since its postExecute....

Answer (score -1):

I think you didn't declare you controller method in the route , it should be like this

```
Route::controller('ajaxHandler', 'ajaxhandlerController@execute');
```

Comment: this controller will have many functions all ajax so i cannot do what u said :)

Comment: Since this route is defined on a controller. So specifying method is not required.